# how do I indicate a javascript generated ID using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I'm counting the number of p tags in a certain div with individual IDs where the p tags and the IDs are randomly generated by php and in varying numbers but in a patterned ID (otherUser1, otherUser2, otherUser3, etc.)

```
for (var i = 1; i <= numUsers; i++) {
    var tagId = '#otherUser' + i + '';
    document.write(tagId);
    var userName = $(tagId).html();
    document.write(userName);
}
```

when I document write the userName variable above, it gives me null because just inserting the variable tagId in the jQuery brackets doesn't do the job. How do I do this properly? - I don't mind either using javascript or jQuery, either is fine.

Comment: It should work assuming the elements have id's `otherUser1`, `otherUser2`, etc. Also you don't need to add an empty string at the end of i (ex `var tagId= "#otherUser"+ i;`)

Comment: lol, I spent nearly an hour trying to figure it out. Looked at your comment and realized I had an extra quote in my php file that was generating the IDs, and nothing wrong with my javascript file. Thanks for the comment, does upvoting your comment give you any points?

Comment: You are using document.write? This usually only works right on scripts run in the rendering of the page, if run from an event it usually replaces the page with the output. BUT if run during page render the ID might not have been loaded into the dom and would not be reachable with jQuery?

Comment: document.write did work tho after I fixed my php code. Anyhow, it was only for testing purposes and I didn't use document.write in my final javascript code.

Comment: Then add an answer detailing what solved the problem and set the answer as accepted (even if it is your own) so that the question is not listed as unanswered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried this using [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js). This is very well working with my localhost. But, still I don't this will solve your issue or not.

I have implemented javaScript as :

```
            function submit(){
                var numUsers=3;
                for (var i = 1; i <= numUsers; i++) {
                    var tagId = '#otherUser' + i;
                    var userName = $(tagId).text().toString();
                    $('#user').append("Username" + i + " : " + userName + "<br/>");
                }
            }
```

And that your HTML is :

```
        <div id="otherUser1">userName1</div>
        <div id="otherUser2">userName2</div>
        <div id="otherUser3">userName3</div>

        <input type="button" value="Click Me!!" onclick="submit();"/>
        <div id="user"></div>
```

This will display the DIVs currently. But, in place of this HTML, there would be your PHP auto-generated DIVs, that will not be displayed later.

I have also created this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saranghdave/uaFNv/2/). I don't know why this is not working even if being the same !!!

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Thanking You.

***EDIT*** : perhaps the jsfiddle not supporting the functions, (so removed function line from javaScript) ! So, updated the fiddle & that is working properly.